# Выборка за сутки 5 дней назад

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Есть такой запрос, который проводит выборку материалов опубликованных 5 дней назад (время в `UNIXTIME`):

`->condition('created', strtotime('-5 days'), '=');`

Подскажите, как добавить сюда выборку всех материалов за целые сутки 5 дней назад?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: наверное надо указать какой класс вы используете для работы с БД, что бы знать что такое condition. если можно задать два condition то видимо условия >= 5 дней назад (начало суток) _И_ одновременно < 4 дня назад (опять же начало суток)

Comment: Функция выглядит так:   public function load() {
    $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
    $query = $storage->getQuery()
     ->condition('type', 'ad')
    ->condition('created', strtotime('-5 days'), '=');
    $nids = $query->execute();
    return $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
  }

Comment: так добавьте еще один condition, как я сказал выше

Comment: Сделал так, как Вы сказали: ->condition('created', strtotime('-5 days'), '>=')
 ->condition('created', strtotime('-4 days'), '<'); Но, как получить это время начала суток?